# Google Big Query using php scripts, not able to host the api on to the web

Tags: google-bigquery, google-api-php-client

I have tried to implement the connection between by `localhost` and `bigquery api` , using `google-api-php-client` , it works all fine , but then i tried to host it on to a website , and I am getting a fatal error saying ,

```
Fatal error: Class 'Google_ServiceResource' not found in /home/XXXXX/public_html/api/src/contrib/Google_BigqueryService.php on line 25

Fatal error: Class 'Google_Client' not found in /home/XXXXX/public_html/api/sample.php on line 9
```

I am not able to figure out the problem , in `localhost` ,when i use "`api`" folder in my `localhost` it works perfectly fine, but on the web it gives an error.

Comment: Any solutions for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This error is usually due to a PHP script path error. Try using the `__DIR__` variable to provide the path that the PHP script is running, and use that to construct the location of the library. There's *lots* of info on Stack Overflow about this, here's [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5371875/336505).

Also, check out the documentation for the Google API PHP Client library about [how to include](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/wiki/GettingStarted#What_to_do_with_the_files) the client lib files.