# require_once not working as I expect it to

Tags: php, phpunit, require-once

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [relative path in require_once doesn’t work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5371828/relative-path-in-require-once-doesnt-work)

I have a project structure as such:

```
ProjectName/
   src
     test
       TestClass.php
   tests
     TestTestClass.php
```

WhenI try and do `require_once '/ProjectName/src/test/TestClass.php';` into *tests/TestTestClass.php* I get an error from PHP stating that: **no such file or directory.**

I have checked the spelling, I have checked everything. I cannot give it the full `/home/userName/bla/bla` path as I need to hand this off to some one else.

Any ideas?

Comment: You are using an absolute path. Is `/ProjectName` in your absolute root directory?

Comment: Have you tried using relative paths? e.g. `require_once '../src/test/TestClass.php'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected behaviour. When you execute `TestTestClass.php`, your working directory is set to `ProjectName/tests`.

It would be better to use `../src/test/TestClass.php`.

Your path is actually absolute, so you will be working straight from `/`, which is not what you're expecting. If your `include_path` is set to your server's directory root, then your code will work without the first `/`. If you don't wish to rely on `include_path` or arbitrary levelling (with `..`), you can always set an environment variable in your first file that defines the full path to your application root, then use that for all includes.

For example, `/ProjectName/index.php`:

```
define('APPPATH', __DIR__);
```

.. and in `/ProjectName/tests/TestTestClass.php`:

```
require_once APPPATH . '/src/test/TestClass.php';
```

Comment: `require_once` is not a function and therefore doesn't need parenthesis.

Comment: @JasonMcCreary That's why it does not have any.

Comment: @JasonMcCreary Was also missing some substantial stuff, I write then fix ;)

Comment: This plan does not work as the index is never seen, ran or understood when running the php unit tests. How ever ../path/to/file.php works

Comment: @Adam `index.php` was simply an example filename, this can just as well be in a `config.php` which is included. You can simply use a relative path as I first explained to the same effect if it's isolated.

Answer (score 1):

absolute filepaths passed to require/include/require_once/include_once all work from the filesystem root, not to the webserver root

Answer (score 0):

Use the special **DIR** to get the current path of the script and like so it will be easier for you to find script paths:

```
require_once(__DIR__ . '../folder/whatever.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd benefit from creating a *path constant* for your project. This is quiet easy to do with the [`__FILE__`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) constant and [`dirname()`](http://php.net/dirname).

```
define('ROOT_PATH', dirname(__FILE__));
```

The above could be put in a configuration file so it is easier to include files throughout your project.

```
require_once ROOT_PATH . '/src/test/TestClass.php';
```

I'd also suggest looking into an [autoloader](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php).