# PHP: sytax error unexpected 'require_once' on registration page

Tags: php, syntax-error, registration, user-registration

I'm trying to create a registration page from a HTML form that validates through to the PHP page (code supplied below), However, when I submit the form, i get the following error:

> ( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'require_once' (T_REQUIRE_ONCE)  in path/user_create.php

Here's the code that enters the input from the form into the database:

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once __DIR__.'config.php';


if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$username=$_POST['username'];
$password=$_POST['password'];
$email=$_POST['email'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO users ( username, password, email) VALUES ( :username, :password, :email )";

$query = $dbh->prepare( $sql );
$query->execute( array( ':username'=>$username, ':password'=>$password, ':address'=>$address, ':email'=>$email ) );

$result = $query->execute( array( ':username'=>$username, ':password'=>$password, ':email'=>$email ) );

if ( $result ){
  echo "<p>Your Registration is complete</p>";
} else {
  echo "<p>There was a problem with registration, please try again.</p>";
}
}

?>
```

Can anyone tell me how to stop this error? Not sure if it an error in the syntax or something else?

Comment: put brackets after require_once.

Comment: @anantkumarsingh I don't think OP has a constant defined with `DIR`; Can't reproduce the error. Are you sure you show us your **real** code and the correct file?

Comment: `require_once(__DIR__.'config.php');` try that. Should work.

Comment: Real code? Yes this is the file i'm using exactly as I have displayed it and yes its the correct file.

Comment: You don't need parentheses for `require_once`, it is a language construct, not a function.

Comment: @jeroen I took my comment from this one http://stackoverflow.com/a/5371875/ ;-) but I might have missed the slash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only error I can see is the missing slash. According to the manual:

> ... This directory name does not have a trailing slash unless it is
>   the root directory.

So you need:

```
require_once __DIR__.'/config.php';
                      ^ here
```

Comment: Nice catch! But it doesn't explain why OP gets an `unexpected require_once` :)

Comment: require_once will throw an fatal error if the specified file is not in the given path, since in the above line '/' is missed and thats the reason it throws an error... and _DIR_ will give document root path without slash

Comment: That's why I think OP doesn't show us the correct file which produces this error OR he doesn't show the real code, which may has some things before `require_once` or he has an [zero-width-space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space) in the script

Comment: @VinodkumarSaravana The warning would be different and it would be a runtime error, not a parse error.

Comment: @Rizier123 Yeah, sounds like another place or file with a missing `;` at the end of the previous line or something like that.

Comment: @user1830632 A bit unexpected, but great!

Comment: @jeroen Yeah, I did miss that slash after all ;-) *More coffee per favor*

Comment: @jeroen Grazie mille!

Comment: @jeroen I would say: `Sack Overflow question parse error: unexpected accept` :) Well it fixed it for OP, so all is fine. (But it's a bit weird because it doesn't match the error which OP got)