# How to check absolute pathnames of files on Heroku

Tags: php, postgresql, heroku

How can I check absolute pathnames of files  on `Heroku`?
I put files in `dropbox` and connect it to `Heroku`.

I need to know absolute pathnames of files because I've read that I need to set absolute pathnames to use `'require_once'` not to get errors.

Thanks!

Comment: Does [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5371828/relative-path-in-require-once-doesnt-work) help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [relative path in require\_once doesn't work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5371828/relative-path-in-require-once-doesnt-work)