# require_once doesn't work when the file is relative to the root, but works when relative to the current location

Tags: php, html, require-once

This works: `require_once '../../include/common.php'`
But this doesn't: `require_once '/include/common.php'`
But this works: `<a href = '/include/common.php'>`

I get this error:
Warning: require_once(/include/common.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C://C:\wamp64\www\src\views\search.php

If it works as a link, why doesn't it work for require_once?

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Are there any `errors`.

Comment: see this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5371828/relative-path-in-require-once-doesnt-work

Comment: Yup, sorry I forgot to include that!  

Warning: require_once(/include/common.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

Using relative paths in require_once is generally considered as bad practice leading to error-prone situations.

The better solution is to set include_path in your php.ini file correctly.

Or you can use something like this:

```
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . "/../../yourscript.php";
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: You can also use `require_once(__DIR__."/../../yourscript.php");` for more recent versions of PHP.

Answer (score 0):

If you have problems with *require_once*, always use absolute path (file system), like this:

`require_once '/folder1/folder2/folder3/file.php'`

In your case `require_once '/include/common.php'` is not "relative to the root". It's an absolute file system path that doesn't exist.

Try and `print_r(__DIR__);` in the folder were you want to include a file and see the absolute path to the file system.

The following `<a href = '/include/common.php'>` works because it's relative to domain name.

[Reading this](https://phpdelusions.net/articles/paths) might help you understand the differences between **file system path** and **web server path**.

Answer (score 0):

```
require_once '/include/common.php'
```

and

```
<a href = '/include/common.php'>
```

they not pointed on the same file.
In first case, you will include `common.php` in `/include` at the root of the system file.
In second case, you will include `common.php` in `/include` at the root of the VHost.

That's why `../../include/common.php` are different of `/include/common.php`