# The require function cannot identify and load the php file of the current folder

Tags: php, wordpress

My question may be strange, but it really confused me!

In my child theme, I used to call and load the files next to the `function.php` file without any problem, but after deleting and re-inserting all the files in the child folder, it is not possible to identify the files. I used the following commands.

Inside the `function.php` file, I call its side file, the `user_function.php` file, but it is not recognized even with the command

```
if (file_exists('user_function.php')) {
     require_once('user_function.php');
} else {
     echo "Please try back in 30 minutes...\n";
     die;
}
```

The file is not recognized! and displays the error message!!!

Of course, my site is loaded, but when I go to `wp-admin`, it is clear that the `user_function.php` file is not loaded.

I have only these two files in my child theme folder:

- `function.php`
- `user_function.php`

Where is the problem from? (These instructions are not really complicated or difficult and I have used these instructions many times before in different places, but now they are challenging me)

I switched several times between other themes and even the parent template

**+update:**

I ran into a strange problem! Now, every other file that I want to load into **function.php** and **user_function.php**, I have to address it with **`__DIR__`**, I think the problem must be somewhere else!
I sent a hosting ticket, they say that a problem happened a few hours ago and the connection with the database was disconnected, and they did not explain what happened, but I think that this must have caused the problem and damaged my WordPress path or addresses. Is it possible that the problem is from Did this happen?

Comment: Please use the following code to see what folder it addresses:
foreach (scandir('.') as $file)
     echo $file. "\n";

Comment: It displays these files!!! /// about.php 
admin-ajax.php 
admin-footer.php 
admin-functions.php 
admin-header.php 
admin-post.php 
admin.php 
async-upload.php 
authorize-application.php 
comment.php 
credits.php  and...

Comment: I don't have these files in the child theme folder or even the parent theme!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You have discovered that there is a working directory. See https://www.php.net/getcwd and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory . Additionally consult your operating systems user and administration manual to lean about the basic properties of a process (standard streams, command line, working directory and environment). PHP runs as a process and executes the PHP code you write.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [relative path in require\_once doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5371828/relative-path-in-require-once-doesnt-work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be due to the fact that the `function.php` is called from another file in another directory.

In order to avoid ambiguities, you can use a full path by providing [`__DIR__`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.magic.php), that returns the directory of the current file, so that PHP will search for the `user_function.php` file in the same directory than the `function.php` file:

```php
// in function.php
if (file_exists(__DIR__.'/user_function.php')) {
     require_once(__DIR__.'/user_function.php');
} else {
     echo "Please try back in 30 minutes...\n";
     die;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, can I find the file that causes this to happen? Why didn't this happen before? Could it be a problem with hosting?!

Comment: I ran into a strange problem! Now, every other file that I want to load into function.php and user_function.php, I have to address it with __DIR__, I think the problem must be somewhere else!
I sent a hosting ticket, they say that a problem happened a few hours ago and the connection with the database was disconnected, and they did not explain what happened, but I think that this must have caused the problem and damaged my WordPress path or addresses. Is it possible that the problem is from Did this happen?

Comment: This must not be a problem. Quite the opposite, it is generally recommended to use `__DIR__`.